# mouseover and mouseout events jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a DIV menu when the user mouseover an icon. The div menu also has two child divs which have onclick events. When I mouse over the icon the menu div appears but when I am about to select the child divs the main menu div hides.

```
     <div id="actionMenu" style="display:none;width:40px;height:30px;background-color:white;z-index:9">
            <div id="addRowDiv">Add</div           >
            <div id="deleteRowDiv">Delete</div>
        </div>

$(actionImage).mouseover(function(e) {

        // get the coordinates
        var x = e.pageX - 40;
        var y = e.pageY - 10;

        $("#actionMenu").css({

            position:"absolute",
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px"
        });   


        $("#actionMenu").attr("rowId", $(td).parent().attr("id"));

        $("#actionMenu").show();
    });

$("#actionMenu").mouseout(function() {

        $(this).hide();

    });


    $("#actionMenu").find("#addRowDiv").click(function() {

        alert('add row clicked');

    });
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I have a table which is populated with data. One of the columns is an icon (actionImage). When I hover over the icon I want to display the div menu (done). The div menu has two child divs (add and delete). Now, when I hover over the child divs the main div (actionMenu) disappears. Why does it disappear since the child divs are inside the action menu div?

Comment: Might want to clean up the code. What's $(actionImage) referring to?

Comment: Where do you want the menu to appear when you mouse over the icon? Do you want the menu to run along your cursor while you move your mouse over the icon?

Comment: I just updated with more details!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are hiding the `#actionMenu` on mouseout.

So What is happening is, when you are inside the icon, the div is shown and also hides (I assume the icon is positioned outside `#actionMenu`). And In the end the `#actionMenu` div is hidden since you are outside before entering the div.

**Edit**: Below seems to solve the problem. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Z22mA/2/) here

```
$("#actionMenu").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried to use mouseenter and mouseleave but they are not recognized by IE8.

Comment: @azamsharp Did my demo work in IE8? mouseenter and mouseleave are there since jQuery 1.0. There must be some other script error.

Comment: See @ShankarSangoli answer. That will work too since you have positioned the div over the icon.

Comment: Yes your code works in IE! I will check why it is not working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It happens because when you mouseover on the menu item to `click`, `mouseout` event is also fired on the menu div along with `mouseover` event on the menu item so the menu div hides. Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event combination it will solve this issue.

```
$(actionImage).mouseenter(function(e) {

        // get the coordinates
        var x = e.pageX - 40;
        var y = e.pageY - 10;

        $("#actionMenu").css({

            position:"absolute",
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px"
        });   


        $("#actionMenu").attr("rowId", $(td).parent().attr("id"));

        $("#actionMenu").show();
    });

$("#actionMenu").mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).hide();

    });


    $("#actionMenu").find("#addRowDiv").click(function() {

        alert('add row clicked');

    });
```

Comment: I tried to use mouseenter but it says object not found. It does not recognize the mouseenter event. I am using jQuery 1.7 and IE 8.